# Export Canvas Charts to png and pdf

Tags: javascript, charts, export, chart.js, data-visualization

I am working on a data visualization project and I have used the Chart.js library for drawing and now I need to export the charts in pdf and png format, what is the best way for me to do it correctly? Thanks for helping my friends ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a feature to allow a user to download the created charts into a image, you can use the ['toDataURL()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) function, and specify the canvas of each chart.

To download a canvas as a pdf you can use the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library, using the above function to retrieve the canvas and then specifying the dimensions.

I may be wrong but I believe you need to create the charts and display on a web page before converting them to an image/pdf. Hope this helps!